Old cartoon/anime where a group consisting of several guys and girls fought with some kind of evil force that looked like a witch/demon woman
When I was a kid, I watched an old cartoon/anime. All I remember is that a group consisting of several guys and girls fought against some kind of evil force that looked like a woman—perhaps a witch or demon. The anime was, in my opinion, in a post-apocalyptic style. Their last battle involved our heroes staging a raid on this evil woman, who was in some high tower.
During the battle, she infected one guy from the good team, and he lost control of himself. An iron weapon appeared on his hand, repeating the shape of the hand but with long sharp claws. He had a red cloak, his hair was dyed white, and he wore something like an iron mask. He destroyed that tower with one blow.
Can anyone identify this cartoon/anime? I've already ruled out Claymore.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

When did you watch this cartoon/anime?
